# Can't run a very old ASP and flash project

Tags: c#, asp.net, frameworks

I come from JS world and have to run an old ASP project to see its structure.
But I can't understand what kind of framework have been used to create this.

Have tried to build it with dotnet but it's not recognized.
Here is the projects screenshot can some body recognize it and tell me how to run it locally ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try opening this would Visual Studio. That does look like a typcial asp.net web forms proejct.

If you ahve a ".sln" file in the root folder, then you should be able to open this project with Visual Stuido. (just download 2019, or latest 2022).

You will almost for certain want to open this project with VS.

If there is no .sln file in the root folder, then choose from VS to open as web site.

So, there are two ways to open/use/develop these older asp.net applications. the existence of a .sln file tends to tip you off as to which method you need (and want) to open up this applcation with. But, yes, you need VS .net "IDE" and the built in designers to work on this.

So, from your screen shot, go up one folder - look for a .sln file. That's the project file you want to try and open with Visual Studio.

As noted, if no .sln, or no .prj file exists, then use the open as web site option in VS.

Comment: Thank you ! I will try it and let you know tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [WebForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/) project, not sure about the state of WebForms support for VSCode but Visual Studio Community should be able to run this. Try loading this project with Visual Studio ensuring you have ASP Web development work load installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Albert completed your answer I will try this and come back soon !